# file-manager and ffmpegthumbnailer

Tags: filemanager, thumbnails

I have PCManFM installed on xubuntu along with ffmpegthumbnailer. Everything works fine except for some configurations like video border, some file formats like flv and so on. How could I change those settings that the file-manager uses to access ffmpegthumbnailer. Is it located somewhere in the `usr/share` directories?

Answer (score 2):

1. Navigate to `/usr/share/thumbnailers`
2. Edit the file `ffmpegthumbnailer.thumbnailer`
3. Flags such as `-f` can be set for removing frames and additional mime types could be added for extending thumbnail feature to those types.